# Python/Pandas DataFrame with leapfrog assigned columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I would like to kindly approach you with request for help and support with mine conundrum.
I am working at moment of refresher of old issue and it occurred me to work on improvements :))).

I am creating DataFrame for future analysis from multiple Excel Files.
When file contains always multiple columns which are transposed to rows and than connected to DF.
So fa so good.

However once I start generating additional columns by generating columns names based on readied entry from Excel.
I am having a issue find some elegant solution for this for sure trivial problem.

Example:

```
dat1 = {'A':[3, 1], 'B':[4, 1]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data = dat1)


this is DataFrame df_1:
   A  B
0  a3  b4
1  a1  b1


dat2 = {'U':[9,9], 'Y':[2,2]}   
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data = dat2)


this is DataFrame df_2:
   U  Y
0  u9  y2
1  u9  y2
```

Wished output is to assigne value to DF by columns name for multiple entries (assign complete DF to another one):

```
dat3 = {'A':[], 'U':[], 'B':[], 'Y':[]}
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data = dat3)


this is DataFrame df_3:
    A   U   B  Y
0  a3  u9  b4  y2
1  a1  u9  b1  y2
```

At moment I am elaborating with all Join/Merge/Concat function but non of them is able to do do it by itself.
I can imagine to try to create new DF or assign according some index however this seems as overshoot for this. Main column name list is made separately in separate function.

Please is there any simple way which I am missing?

Many thanks for your time, consideration and potential help in advance.

Best Regards
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `concat` method to concatenate the data frames as the following:
First, creating the data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
dat1 = {'A':[3, 1], 'B':[4, 1]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data = dat1) 
df_1
```

output:

```
    A   B
0   3   4
1   1   1


dat2 = {'U':[9,9], 'Y':[2,2]}   
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data = dat2)
df_2     

    U   Y
0   9   2
1   9   2
```

Then use `concat` method:

```
df_3 = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)
df_3
```

output:

```
    A   B   U   Y
0   3   4   9   2
1   1   1   9   2
```

The last step is to rearrange `df_3` columns to get an output similar to the one you have shown in your question, you should use:

```
df_3 = df_3[['A', 'U', 'B', 'Y']]
df_3
```

output:

```
    A   U   B   Y
0   3   9   4   2
1   1   9   1   2
```

Comment: Hi Yasser, thanks for you answer and solution is really elegant. I will most definitely test it. I was wondering if some of mentioned functions  as { concat, merge, join } would not manage it in one shot :) ... since I was looking in to documentation and could not find one step solution so I would say it is not present in current pandas. Many thanks for your help and HAPPY NEW YEAR!!!

Comment: Hi @JanM., it was my pleasure to help you, and happy new year to you as well!